# Automapper transform parent child relationship to object with properties from parent and child

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Im trying to get Automapper to transform a parent child relationship to one list with properties from both parent and child.

My structure looks like this

```
public class ItemEntity {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string key {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<ItemVersionEntity> Versions {get; set;} 
}

public class ItemVersionEntity {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

Im trying to get automapper help me transform this into

```
public class ItemDto{
  // from Item
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string key {get;set;}

  // from ItemVersion
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public DateTime Date {get;set;}
  
}
```

So if an ItemEntity contains a list of four ItemVersionEntity i will end up with a ItemDto List with 4 entries.

I can easily map ItemEntity to a ItemDto and just as easy map ItemVersionEntity to a ItemDto, but how can i 'combine' it to get a single list back

```
public class RepositoryMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public RepositoryMappingProfile()
    {
       CreateMap<ItemEntity , ItemDto>();
       CreateMap<ItemVersionEntity , ItemDto>();

       // what to write here to map to a List<ItemDto> ? 
    }
}
```

Should i do it without automapper, it would be something like

```
 List<ItemEntity> all = new List<ItemEntity>() {
        new ItemEntity() {
            Id=1,
            key="a",
            Versions = new List<ItemVersionEntity>() {
                new ItemVersionEntity() { Name="name1", Date=DateTime.Now },
                new ItemVersionEntity() { Name="name2", Date=DateTime.Now },
            }
        }
    };
        
    List<ItemDto> mappedDto = new List<ItemDto>();
    foreach(var ie in all) {
        mappedDto.AddRange(ie.Versions.Select(v => new ItemDto() { Id=ie.Id, key = ie.key,  Name=v.Name, Date = v.Date }));
    }
```

Which returns

```
Id | key | Name  | Date
1  | a   | name1 | 10/09/2020 09:37:14 
1  | a   | name2 | 10/09/2020 09:37:14
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: How does that help? I cant find any solutions to my problem there, am i missing something

Comment: How would you do it by hand, without AM? Show us the code.

Comment: I've updated the question with a explanation on how to do it without Automapper

Comment: As the docs explain, AM only maps one to one, so the code to resolve the mismatch, you'll have to write that yourself. But you'll have to decide how helpful is AM as this point. For only a few properties, perhaps just write it by hand.

Comment: Well, it is not just a few properties, the entities in question are much more complex.
I have considered adding a parent ItemEntity to the ItemVersionEntity and then just use 
`CreateMap<ItemVersionEntity , ItemDto>().ForMember(d => d.Id, src=> src.MapFrom(s => s.Parent.Id));` but that would require me to rewrite the Entity Framework stuff and i would really prefer to avoid that.

Comment: Then you'll have to mix and match, some LINQ and some AM. There are many similar examples, you just have to find the right mix for your case.

Comment: That is what i'm trying to by asking this question, if i was able to find a useful example, i wouldn't have to ask, right :)